# Limit SSH User to a shell command

Tags: git, shell, ssh

### My question is

how can I allow an user to ssh to my server with limitation to a shell command and a directory?

### My situation

I'm using git to deploy code to my Server. I have 2 servers, 1st one is product server, 2nd one is a git server.

My team use git server to pull/push code.

At my product server, I setup git client. Whenever I want to publish a version, I push it to my git server (master or other branches ...), then I ssh into my product server to pull the code.

I want to share the code pulling privilege with my teammates, but don't want to allow them to run any command but *git*, and limit them in a directory only.

The owner of directory that I want to limit is apache:apache, so it will be very good if the ssh user run by apache privilege.

Thank you,

**Solved**: I've used [lshell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell) with a limit set of commands.

Comment: I think you might be looking for this. Click here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login

Answer (score 12):

A simple command to disable the shell in a git user is to replace the */usr/bin/bash* with */usr/bin/git-shell*. Replace it in the /etc/password file or using the command:

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/git-shell [username]
```

Check this document from the official Git website: [Setting Up the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).
Additional info if you want to have a shell on it but limiting it to a directory use:
[rbash](http://man.he.net/man1/rbash). Same as git-shell just replace the user shell with it.

Comment: I've tried to use git-shell but did not know how to put the other commands to ~/git-shell-commands, the default commands are just *help* and *list*.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

You should consider **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**, which is an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) which can [ssh forced command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work/13320256#13320256).

And ssh forced command is there precisely to limit ssh to one unique command (in the case of gitolite, a script which will control access right, and make sure only git commands are executed).

[image: forced command]

Even if you *don't* use gitolite, ssh forced command alone (not linked to git at all) is still interesting to consider, in order to control and limit what a user can do through an ssh session.

---

The [OP Tarzan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142567/tarzan), [who didn't want to install another service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683272/limit-ssh-user-to-a-shell-command/16684537#comment24046731_16684537), installed another service ([Ishell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell)), which is precisely based on ssh forced command ;)

Comment: My product Server has a production website running on it, so I do not want to setup more services (like gitolite), I've just setup git client. 

However on my git server, I did setup gitolite & gitlab on it. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Tarzan forced command is a feature of ssh and doesn't require to install any additional service.

Comment: @Tarzan I have included IShell in the answer: it uses forced command, exactly as I recommended in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I meant that gitolite is a system, that heavier and bigger than lshell. Sorry about wrong explain.

Comment: @Tarzan I understand. But the suggestion of using forced command is still valid, is it not?