# interactive services for a git user on GITLAB

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I installed gitlab and when I try to do the following:

```
ssh git@domain.com
```

I get the following error

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Welcome to GitLab, Jhon!

Connection to domain.com closed.
```

I read the following comment in one of the threads:

> You cannot ssh to the gitlab server as git user, that is not allowed even if you have added your your ssh key via gitlab. You can only push/pull as the git user. You can login as the root user if need be.

Is this true for all cases. I installed gitlab on centos 6.5. I just want to make sure that we cannot enable interactive services for a git user on gitlab and the result i got was the one that should be expected.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to make sure that we cannot enable interactive services for a git user on gitlab and the result i got was the one that should be expected.

Yes, except you can get rid of the first error message with:

```
ssh -T git@domain
```

See "[What is Pseudo TTY-Allocation? (SSH and Github)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907289/6309)"

GitLab, like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html), uses ssh with **[forced command only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684537/6309)**, meaning no interactive shell.

Note: the git shell error message "`What do you think I am? A shell?`"  is no longer [present since git 1.7.4, January 2011](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e69164ddb9d6092a94915bb984749d48f598cea8), and now reads:

```
 Interactive git shell is not enabled
```