# gitlab: invocation of gitlab-shell

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab

I have been going through the code of [gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell). I am unable to understand how it is invoked. If I made a pull to my server(on which gitlab-shell is installed), how does gitlab-shell knows about it? [bin/gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/bin/gitlab-shell#L15) has this line as comment:

> GitLab shell, invoked from ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Is there any line in `authorized_keys` which invokes gitlab-shell? (sounds unlikely).

Comment: Have you looked at the authorized keys file.that gitlab installs ?   It should answer your question.

Comment: here is the line which does that: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/bin/install#L16 I don't see anything special with it.

Comment: Thanks doon! It was content of authorized keys indeed. Here is a clue: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/4d30c0c5d3d0f23a221ee507b6bd110a539b8570/spec/gitlab_keys_spec.rb#L25

Comment: Yep :) you can run the command on connect.  Quite handy for building systems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [blob line you mention](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/4d30c0c5d3d0f23a221ee507b6bd110a539b8570/spec/gitlab_keys_spec.rb#L25) builds the authorized_keys line as:

```
"command=\"#{ROOT_PATH}/bin/gitlab-shell [auserID]\",\
   no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa [aPubKey]
```

That is taking advantage of an SSH feature (not related to Git or GitLab), called "**[forced command](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214110102/http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858)**".
You can see illustrated [in gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684537/6309), [which explains](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh/index.html#restricting-shell-accessdistinguishing-one-user-from-another) the forced command allows for:

- restricting shell access
- distinguishing one user from another

In the case of GitLab, that allows to limit SSH calls to `gitlab-shell`.