# What happens when I run "ssh git@gitlab.com

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have tried google it and check the gitlab-documentation but did not find a good answer for this.

When I setup GitLab I am advised to test my SSH-keys to my GitLab URL instance.
I use git@gitlab.com.

What actually happens when I run "ssh git@gitlab.com"
I understand how you use SSH to login to a remote device e.g. Cisco Router with SSH Admin. But in this case: who is git@gitlab.com? [username]@gitlab.com makes more sense to me.

Somehow it must find my Gitlab account (since it is there my public key is stored). How can I do that when I use a generic git@gitlab.com ?

I am after a more step-by-step answer (Client-Server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `[username]@gitlab.com` makes more sense to me

It would not: that would ask to open an SSH session as 'username': that account does not exist. Only one account exists: 'git'.

Then, in `~/.ssh/authrorized_keys`, your public key is found, alongside:

- an ID (as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776498/6309)), matching your registered GitLab account,
- a [forced command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309), which will call a GitLab script in order to execute the Git command.

That way:

- there is no interractive session possible on GitLab's server
- the project [gitlab-shell](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell) gets your ID and hangle your Git query

Comment: Thanks for answer but it generates a new question: doesnt everyone use ’git’ to test their ssh.pub-key? I think I am missing some fundemental knowledge regarding GitLab. So when you open the ssh-session with username ’git’ the gitlab-server recognize the user by the id from autherized_keys? How could the server otherwise know who wants to open the session?

Comment: @Aard Yes, the ID matches your GitLab account, that way, the GitLab script called by SSH will know who is requesting a Git operation. No need to use anything but 'git' to test your connection.

Answer (score 0):

for found it, go in repository on clone, select ssh, begin start copy  up to :,
now test

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).