# What about 'git reset --hard' with read permission (local/remote)?

Tags: git, permissions, reset, gitolite

I'm new to Git and I am trying to understand the concept. Maybe someone can help me with a few theoretical questions?

So there is a Git on the remote server and a cloned git on my local computer.

After cloning the git to my local computer with a read permission (gitolite with 'R' permission), can I do any damage to the git on the remote server?

If I do a '`git reset --hard`' (I know that there is often a strong advise against it), does this only reset the changes on my local computer or also on the remote server?
Is there a difference if I work with `R` or `RW+` authorization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, [Git](https://git-scm.com/) itself has no notion of 'R' or 'RW+': those are read-write permission managed by [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html), an *authorization* layer called through SSH [(forced command: the ~git/.ssh/Authorized_keys file calls the gitolite script)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684537/6309) or HTTPS.

[`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---hard) is purely a local function, which does involve:

- Git only, not gitolite
- your local repository only, not the remote repository behind Gitolite.

If you were to reset HEAD to a different commit, the only way to push that new HEAD would be through the Git operation `git push --force`.

That is where Gitolite comes, with the [permission field](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#the-permission-field) of the [access rules](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#access-rules) included in the (remote) [gitolite-admin repository](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin).

Only an access rule including RW+ would allow you to `push --force`.
`R` is only for cloning and fetching, it prevents pushing (force or not).