# Login to the multiple UNIX servers one by one and then execute the command using perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to login to the multiple `UNIX` servers using `SSH` one by one and then need to be executed the commands without prompt the username and password.

Is there any chance to do this from `Perl`?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this with using a combination of SSH features, regular shell scripts, etc and I do it quite often. Yet even though my primary language is Perl, it's never my weapon of choice for this task. Is there a reason you specifically want to do this using Perl?  Also, do you have the opportunity to do password-less login via SSH keys because that resolves that portion of your question entirely

Comment: use Net::OpenSSH and/or Net::OpenSSH::Parallel!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done, and if you do, it's best to use a module for it, e.g. [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::OpenSSH).

But this is probably a bad idea. You will need to specify the username and password in plaintext in a place where your Perl script can read them (e.g. in its source code). Anyone who can read your script can also read the username and password, and execute any remote command that using them permits.

So you might as well create a different piece of information that can be read by anyone who can read the Perl script, and use that to authenticate: a passwordless SSH key.

Create one and add its public key to the authorized keys on the host(s) you want to execute your remote command on.  Use that key to execute the remote command.  This is as least as safe as hardcoding the username and password in a place where the Perl script can read them.

In fact, it is safer: you can [restrict the use of that key to the command you want to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login).

And you won't need a Perl script to execute the remote command.