# provide custom terminal session to incoming ssh connections in c++

Tags: c++, unix, ssh, terminal

We have a server that run with certain functionality. We want to enable some users with ssh authentication so that if an ssh session is initiated by the clients **on certain port** to the server, the sever will provide a custom terminal which supports only very few commands we have decided to implement.

My question is: how can I listen (in cpp) to incoming ssh connections, and after successful authentication provide them a terminal application.

Is there a package that supports some of that functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sshd` of course is configurable, and can be made to listen on different ports.  These discuss it at length:

- *[Change the default SSH port](http://linuxlookup.com/howto/change_default_ssh_port)*
- *[Getting SSH to listen to different ports on different interfaces](http://fatphil.org/linux/ssh_ports.html)*

The underlying issue is what would one do with this.  That has been asked before, with suggestions to setup a [restricted shell](http://www.tecmint.com/rbash-a-restricted-bash-shell-explained-with-practical-examples/) (including using [chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot)).  For discussion, see

- *[How to create a restricted SSH user for port forwarding?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding)*
- *[How to restrict SSH users to a predefined set of commands after login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login)*
- *[Securing restricted shell environments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9720/securing-restricted-shell-environments)*
- *[Best Practices for UNIX chroot() Operations](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/chroot-practices.html)*

Comment: Hi Thomas!! Thanks for the great answer. Actually, I originally thought about launching some terminal-mockup to logged-in user.

Something like live interaction with python Cmd module [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html).
So that the client will be restricted to a finite custom set of commands...

Comment: I guess there should be some simple way to redirect the shell into a certain script, right?

Comment: You could run your application within the `script` program.  Some versions (different operating systems) are more capable, but "any" Unix has it.