# Allow specific commands to non-interactive linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

I need to restrict access to 1 of my linux servers . so i added to my "authorized_keys" file before the key :

```
no-pty ssh-rsa ..............
```

I disabled the password access to this machine from couple of ip's

In the seconds server that running ansible i need to success "Deploying" to the restricted server .

i need to know how i can permit couple of commands :

rsync
scp
Also i would like to disable the option to run commands to the restricted server like that :

```
ssh ***.***.***.*** | bash "date"
```

So once i'll run the ansible playbook i will be able to rsync / scp files to the restricted server

how can i do that ?

Thanks a lot ! Amit

Comment: `ssh .... | bash "date"` will not run any commands on the remote host. That will run `ssh` with no commands and then feed the output of the `ssh` session to the standard input of `bash "date"` (which is an error as `bash` will not find a `date` file). So that's not the command you meant there.

Comment: i just gave an example . i can connect to the remote host ( restricted host ) if i'll run "ssh ***.***.***.***  bash " or every command like that i would like to disable this too .

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login

Comment: @larks it's not a duplicated topic CAUSE will not work in this setup , thanks !

Comment: Cause rsync command will not work *